# appending object references to python list with boost

Tags: c++, python, list, boost, reference

I have a vector of pointers to objects in c++ and want to expose it to python with a list. So far I gave a reference of a python list to c++. I figured pointers are not suitable for python so I read about how to make a pointer to a reference by (*obj) it. But when I call: myList.append((*obj)); python just crashes. Can someone tell me how to put objects I only have pointers of into a python list correctly so I can manipulate that list later?

Greetings
Chris

Comment: i figured, i could add a reference of an object known to boost python by defining the class, but not an unknown object. i don't know why it just crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the Problem appears when the type is not declared for boost::python. !